# Change element name based on attribute value XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to do something simple (or so I thought) using XSLT.
I want to split a list of elements to two, rename an element using 
The idea is that a xml formed like this:

```
<elem at="value" id="something"/>
<elem at="value" id="something2"/>
<elem at="random" id="something3"/>
```

will be converted to:

```
<elemVal id="something"/>
<elemVal id="something2"/>
<elemRa id="something3"/>
```

(the  new element names are static)
So the elements are renamed based on the value of an attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elem/@at[.='value']">
    <xsl:element name="elemVa">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

So far I have an identity template, but I don't understand how I can go backwards and change the elements name, keeping it's content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:template match="elem/@at[.='value']">
```

you need

```
<xsl:template match="elem[@at ='value']">
```

then create the new element (a literal suffices) and make sure the `at` attribute is not processed:

```
<xsl:template match="elem[@at ='value']">
    <elemVa>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @at | node()"/>
    </elemVa>
</xsl:template>
```

The above is XSLT/XPath 2.0, in 1.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="elem[@at ='value']">
    <elemVa>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'at')] | node()"/>
    </elemVa>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps explain the difference between the 2 match?

Comment: You want to transform the element, therefore the right approach is to match on the element (with a predicate describing the attribute condition). Your attempt matches on the attribute node, that does not enable you to transform the element.

Comment: OK. then one thing is missing, the removal of the attribute that I match upon.

Comment: My suggestion `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @at | node()"/>` respectively `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'at')] | node()"/>` would make sure the attribute is not processed further. Or write a template `<xsl:template match="elem/@at"/>` respectively `<xsl:template match="elem/@at[. = ('value', 'random')]"/>`.

Comment: When tried with the example code, it's working. But I want to match an xsi:type attribute.

Comment: so the attribute would be xsi:type="value"

Comment: With XSLT 2.0 you should be able to use `@* except @xsi:type`, assuming you have the namespace prefix `xsi` declared in your XSLT stylesheet. With XSLT 1.0 you can select `@*[not(name() = 'xsi:type')]`. It might indeed be better to write an empty template along the lines of `<xsl:template match="elem/@xsi:type"/>` or `<xsl:template match="elem/@xsi:type[. = 'foo' or . = 'bar']"/>`.

Comment: Hm indeed, need to use  `name` instead of `local-name`.